# Scala - Get function result in array inside foreach

Tags: scala, apache-spark, azure-databricks

I want to list the folders from provided source paths. It should go first to 2021 directory get paths and store in array and further to 2022 folder.

Then I need to access this array outside foreach and pass to some other fuction. Unable to figure out how I can go about this. Please help.

```
val SourcePaths:Array[String] = Array("abfss://cont@mystorage.dfs.core.windows.net/testdata/2021/","abfss://cont@mystorage.dfs.core.windows.net/testdata/2022/")

SourcePaths.foreach(path=>{
  var allDirPaths:Array[String] = listDirectories(path,true)
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `map` instead of `foreach` (also, don't use arrays, they are bad):

```
val subfolders: Seq[Seq[String]] = sourcePaths.toSeq.map(listDirectories(_, true).toSeq)
```

Or `flatMap` if you want all subfolders as one flat list:

```
val subfolders: Seq[String] = sourceParths.toSeq.flatMap(listDirectories(_, true))
```

Comment: Could you expand on your comment: "Use map instead of foreach (also, don't use arrays, they are bad"?

Comment: @tjheslin1 "expand" it? I don't think it's collapsed right now :)